# merge data from array of object by particular key in javascript

Tags: javascript

hello all I need help in JavaScript I am trying to merger multiple array in once with their key and sum their value below is my object and code.

```
{
    "0": {
        "zone_id": "2",
        "zone_name": "Mumbai",
        "fy_2022_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2022_balance_amt": "1000",
        "fy_2022_balance_count_amt": "1",
        "fy_2022_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2021_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2021_balance_amt": "1000",
        "fy_2021_balance_count_amt": "1",
        "fy_2021_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2020_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2020_balance_amt": "1000.00",
        "fy_2020_balance_count_amt": "1.00",
        "fy_2020_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2019_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2019_balance_amt": "1000.00",
        "fy_2019_balance_count_amt": "1.00",
        "fy_2019_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2018_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2018_balance_amt": "1000.00",
        "fy_2018_balance_count_amt": "1.00",
        "fy_2018_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2017_receipt_amt": "0.00",
        "fy_2017_balance_amt": "500.00",
        "fy_2017_balance_count_amt": "1.00",
        "fy_2017_adjustment_amt": ""
    },
    "1": {
        "zone_id": "2",
        "zone_name": "Mumbai",
        "fy_2022_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2022_balance_amt": "1000",
        "fy_2022_balance_count_amt": "1",
        "fy_2022_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2021_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2021_balance_amt": "1000",
        "fy_2021_balance_count_amt": "1",
        "fy_2021_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2020_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2020_balance_amt": "1000.00",
        "fy_2020_balance_count_amt": "1.00",
        "fy_2020_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2019_receipt_amt": "1000.00",
        "fy_2019_balance_amt": "0.00",
        "fy_2019_balance_count_amt": "0.00",
        "fy_2019_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2018_receipt_amt": "1000.00",
        "fy_2018_balance_amt": "0.00",
        "fy_2018_balance_count_amt": "0.00",
        "fy_2018_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2017_receipt_amt": "500.00",
        "fy_2017_balance_amt": "0.00",
        "fy_2017_balance_count_amt": "0.00",
        "fy_2017_adjustment_amt": ""
    },
    "2": {
        "zone_id": "2",
        "zone_name": "Mumbai",
        "fy_2022_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2022_balance_amt": "1000",
        "fy_2022_balance_count_amt": "1",
        "fy_2022_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2021_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2021_balance_amt": "1000",
        "fy_2021_balance_count_amt": "1",
        "fy_2021_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2020_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2020_balance_amt": "1000.00",
        "fy_2020_balance_count_amt": "1.00",
        "fy_2020_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2019_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2019_balance_amt": "1000.00",
        "fy_2019_balance_count_amt": "1.00",
        "fy_2019_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2018_receipt_amt": null,
        "fy_2018_balance_amt": "1000.00",
        "fy_2018_balance_count_amt": "1.00",
        "fy_2018_adjustment_amt": "",
        "fy_2017_receipt_amt": "500.00",
        "fy_2017_balance_amt": "0.00",
        "fy_2017_balance_count_amt": "0.00",
        "fy_2017_adjustment_amt": ""
    },    
    "year": [
        "2022",
        "2021",
        "2020",
        "2019",
        "2018",
        "2017"
    ]
}
```

i want one single array in that i want all
fy_2017_receipt_amt,
fy_2018_receipt_amt,
fy_2019_receipt_amt,
fy_2020_receipt_amt,
fy_2021_receipt_amt,
fy_2022_receipt_amt
to be sumed and same for other keys like balance_amt and others
all years are dynamically u can see array of years in below

thus is what i tried but i am not getting result as i want

```
for (var b in res.year) {
    for(var i in res) {
        
        
        var yearget = Number(res.year[b]);
        var balamt = `fy_${yearget}_balance_amt`;
        var balcntamt = `fy_${yearget}_balance_count_amt`;
        var adjamt = `fy_${yearget}_adjustment_amt`;
        var recptamt = `fy_${yearget}_receipt_amt`;
        
        zone_response.reduce((a2, c2) => {
            
            let filteredP = a2.filter(el => el.zone_id === c2.zone_id)
            if (filteredP.length > 0) {
                a2[a2.indexOf(filteredP[0])].balamt += +c2.balamt;
                a2[a2.indexOf(filteredP[0])].balcntamt += +c2.balcntamt;
                a2[a2.indexOf(filteredP[0])].recptamt += +c2.recptamt;
                a2[a2.indexOf(filteredP[0])].adjamt += +c2.adjamt;
            } else {
                a2.push(c2);
            }
            return a2;
        }, []);

        var final_filtered_response = [...zone_response.reduce((mp,
            o) => {
            if (!mp.has(o.zone_id)) mp.set(o.zone_id, Object
                .assign({
                    count: 0
                }, o));
            mp.get(o.zone_id).count++;
            return mp;
        }, new Map).values()];
    }
}
```

I need the answer like below

```
{
  "fy_2022_total_count" :0,
  "fy_2022_receipt_amt": 0,
  "fy_2022_balance_amt": 3000,
  "fy_2022_balance_count_amt": 3,
  "fy_2022_adjustment_amt": 0,
  "fy_2021_total_count" :0,
  "fy_2021_receipt_amt": 0,
  "fy_2021_balance_amt": 3000,
  "fy_2021_balance_count_amt": 3,
  "fy_2021_adjustment_amt": 0,
  "fy_2020_total_count" :0,
  "fy_2020_receipt_amt": 0,
  "fy_2020_balance_amt": 3000,
  "fy_2020_balance_count_amt": 3,
  "fy_2020_adjustment_amt": 0,
  "fy_2019_total_count" :1,
  "fy_2019_receipt_amt": 1000,
  "fy_2019_balance_amt": 2000,
  "fy_2019_balance_count_amt": 2,
  "fy_2019_adjustment_amt": 0,
  "fy_2018_total_count" :1,
  "fy_2018_receipt_amt": 1000,
  "fy_2018_balance_amt": 2000,
  "fy_2018_balance_count_amt": 2,
  "fy_2018_adjustment_amt": 0,
  "fy_2017_total_count" :2,
  "fy_2017_receipt_amt": 1000,
  "fy_2017_balance_amt": 500,
  "fy_2017_balance_count_amt": 1,
  "fy_2017_adjustment_amt": 0,
  "year": [ "2022", "2021", "2020", "2019", "2018", "2017"]
}
```

total_count means if balance_amt = 0 count total for that year let say 2017 has two values that has balance_amt=0 so total count 2.
any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: please add the wanted result (data structure/values).

Comment: Your export data is not the best one. You should have two distinct properties like: `{data: [{},{},{}...], years: []}` instead of mixing it all up into a single object. I'd suggest you fix that to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You could build an array and remove unwanted properties and sum same keys as result.

```js
const
    data = {
        0: { zone_id: "2", zone_name: "Mumbai", fy_2022_receipt_amt: null, fy_2022_balance_amt: "1000", fy_2022_balance_count_amt: "1", fy_2022_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2021_receipt_amt: null, fy_2021_balance_amt: "1000", fy_2021_balance_count_amt: "1", fy_2021_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2020_receipt_amt: null, fy_2020_balance_amt: "1000.00", fy_2020_balance_count_amt: "1.00", fy_2020_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2019_receipt_amt: null, fy_2019_balance_amt: "1000.00", fy_2019_balance_count_amt: "1.00", fy_2019_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2018_receipt_amt: null, fy_2018_balance_amt: "1000.00", fy_2018_balance_count_amt: "1.00", fy_2018_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2017_receipt_amt: "0.00", fy_2017_balance_amt: "500.00", fy_2017_balance_count_amt: "1.00", fy_2017_adjustment_amt: "" },
        1: { zone_id: "2", zone_name: "Mumbai", fy_2022_receipt_amt: null, fy_2022_balance_amt: "1000", fy_2022_balance_count_amt: "1", fy_2022_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2021_receipt_amt: null, fy_2021_balance_amt: "1000", fy_2021_balance_count_amt: "1", fy_2021_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2020_receipt_amt: null, fy_2020_balance_amt: "1000.00", fy_2020_balance_count_amt: "1.00", fy_2020_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2019_receipt_amt: "1000.00", fy_2019_balance_amt: "0.00", fy_2019_balance_count_amt: "0.00", fy_2019_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2018_receipt_amt: "1000.00", fy_2018_balance_amt: "0.00", fy_2018_balance_count_amt: "0.00", fy_2018_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2017_receipt_amt: "500.00", fy_2017_balance_amt: "0.00", fy_2017_balance_count_amt: "0.00", fy_2017_adjustment_amt: "" },
        2: { zone_id: "2", zone_name: "Mumbai", fy_2022_receipt_amt: null, fy_2022_balance_amt: "1000", fy_2022_balance_count_amt: "1", fy_2022_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2021_receipt_amt: null, fy_2021_balance_amt: "1000", fy_2021_balance_count_amt: "1", fy_2021_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2020_receipt_amt: null, fy_2020_balance_amt: "1000.00", fy_2020_balance_count_amt: "1.00", fy_2020_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2019_receipt_amt: null, fy_2019_balance_amt: "1000.00", fy_2019_balance_count_amt: "1.00", fy_2019_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2018_receipt_amt: null, fy_2018_balance_amt: "1000.00", fy_2018_balance_count_amt: "1.00", fy_2018_adjustment_amt: "", fy_2017_receipt_amt: "500.00", fy_2017_balance_amt: "0.00", fy_2017_balance_count_amt: "0.00", fy_2017_adjustment_amt: "" },
        year: ["2022", "2021", "2020", "2019", "2018", "2017"]
    },
    prefix = 'fy',
    keys = ['receipt_amt', 'balance_amt', 'balance_count_amt', 'adjustment_amt'],
    result = {};

for (let i = 0; i in data; i++) {
    data.year.forEach(year => {
        const
            totalCount = [prefix, year, 'total_count'].join('_'),
            k = [prefix, year, 'balance_amt'].join('_');

        result[totalCount] ??= 0;
        if (!+data[i][k]) result[totalCount]++;

        keys.forEach(key => {
            const k = [prefix, year, key].join('_');
            result[k] = (result[k] || 0) + (+data[i][k] || 0);
        });
    });
}
result.year = data.year;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @can u help me in one more problem in this how can i count total of object with condition like i want count of 'fy_2017_balance_amt' i want count of all 'fy_2017_balance_amt == 0' same as 2019,2018......so on

Comment: it would be easier if you supply a wanted result. please edit the question for it.

Comment: i edited the question can u please check out thank you so much for help

Comment: Hello can u please check my question again I edited the question as u want. Thank You

Comment: what if i want the result to be >0 instead of =0

Comment: replace `if (!+data[i][k])` with `if (+data[i][k] > 0)`

Comment: thank you so much I got my result as expected u are amazing thank you for helping me thank you for your precious time